# Cant finish my SAML login with python requests

Tags: python-requests, http-post, bots, saml, response-headers

so I'm trying to code this small program to login into my school's "*grades dashboard*". The thing is that the protocol used by my school is SAML, with O365 (Microsoft) as `IDP` and another `SP`. So I have arrived to a point where there are 2 consecutive `POST` sort of post/307/post/302. Both of them reuire of the **EXTACT SAME PAYLOAD** which would be the `SAMLResponse` + `RelayState`. When this action is performed on the browser, both post requests carry the same `Form Data`, however, when )I do it with python, I can't make a dedicated request for each of this post requests sice once it has completed the first one, it automatically redirects to the new location to make the other one, making it impossible for me to dedicate a new request with new headers... for the second post. And to my understanding, the payload will only full-fill the first `Form Data`, not the second. I've tried to force the program to wait using `allow_redirects=False`, this helped me see if the first post request was working, which it did. The second however wasn't working, it retuns the typical sort of "*Restart Login*" location header + the content-lenght doesn't match the one showed by Chrome.

I've also noticed that the first post request doesn't really contribute to anything, there are no cookies nor tokens returned. Also, none of the referers or origins shown by Chrome on the `Request Headers` match the actual "*request-flow*" of the page, Eg: The referer of the 2nd post isn't the url of the 1st post, Isn't that wrong? Could I then just forget of the 1st post and focus only on the 2nd one? Why am I even failing at the login of the 2nd post request?

**CODE**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import unquote
from time import sleep


login_url1 = 'https://sms.eursc.eu/login.php'
login_url2 = 'https://sms.eursc.eu/saml/discover'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.63 Safari/537.36'}

headers1 = {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.63 Safari/537.36'
}

s = requests.session()
s.headers.update(headers)
r1 = s.get(login_url1, headers=headers1)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r1.text, 'html.parser')
print(f'RESPONSE 1: {r1.status_code}, {soup.title}')




headers2 = {
    'authority': 'sms.eursc.eu',
    'sec-ch-ua': '^\\^Google',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '^\\^Windows^\\^',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.63 Safari/537.36',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    'referer': 'https://sms.eursc.eu/login',
    'accept-language': 'es-ES,es;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.7,en-GB;q=0.6',
    'dnt': '1'
}

r2 = s.get(login_url2, headers=headers2)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r2.text, 'html.parser')
login_url3 = r2.url
print(f'RESPONSE 2: {r2.status_code}, {soup.title}')




payload1 = {
  'UserName': 'mail@student.eursc.eu',
  'Password': 'password',
  'AuthMethod': 'FormsAuthentication'
}

headers3 = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'sec-ch-ua': '^\\^Google',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '^\\^Windows^\\^',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'Origin': 'https://sts.eursc.eu',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.63 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
    'Referer': login_url3,
    'Accept-Language': 'es-ES,es;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.7,en-GB;q=0.6',
    'dnt': '1'
}

r3 = s.post(login_url3, data=payload1, headers=headers3)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r3.text, 'html.parser')
print(f'RESPONSE 3: {r3.status_code}, {soup.title}')
print(r3.url)
pre_SAMLResponse = str(str(soup).split('SAMLResponse" type="hidden" value="')[1])
SAMLResponse = str(pre_SAMLResponse.split('"/>')[0])




cookies1 = {
    '_ga': 'GA1.2.158382224.1620157877',
    'LOCAL_LANGUAGE_CODE': 'en',
    'browse_history': '%5B%22%5C%2Fcontent%5C%2Fcommon%5C%2Fdashboard.php%22%5D',
    '_gid': 'GA1.2.1105104913.1630774065',
    '_gat': '1'
}

headers4 = {
    'authority': 'sms.eursc.eu',
    'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
    'sec-ch-ua': '^\\^Google',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '^\\^Windows^\\^',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'origin': 'https://sts.eursc.eu',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'cookie': '_ga=GA1.2.158382224.1620157877; LOCAL_LANGUAGE_CODE=en; browse_history=%5B%22%5C%2Fcontent%5C%2Fcommon%5C%2Fdashboard.php%22%5D; _gid=GA1.2.1105104913.1630774065; _gat=1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.63 Safari/537.36',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    'referer': 'https://sts.eursc.eu/',
    'accept-language': 'es-ES,es;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.7,en-GB;q=0.6',
    'dnt': '1'
}

payload2 = {
    'SAMLResponse': SAMLResponse + '&RelayState=https%3A%2F%2Fsms.eursc.eu%2Fsaml%2Flogin',
}
login_url4 = 'https://sms.eursc.eu/saml/module.php/saml/sp/saml2-acs.php/euroschools'

r4 = s.post(login_url4, data=payload2, headers=headers4, cookies=cookies1, allow_redirects=False)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r4.text, 'html.parser')
print(f'RESPONSE 4: {r4.status_code}, {soup.title}')
print(r4.url)
print(r4.headers)
login_url5 = r4.headers['location']




headers5 = {
    'authority': 'sms.eursc.eu',
    'method': 'POST',
    'path': '/saml/login_check',
    'scheme': 'https',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'es-ES,es;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.7,en-GB;q=0.6',
    'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
    'content-length': '9106',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'cookie': '_ga=GA1.2.158382224.1620157877; LOCAL_LANGUAGE_CODE=en; browse_history=%5B%22%5C%2Fcontent%5C%2Fcommon%5C%2Fdashboard.php%22%5D; _gid=GA1.2.1105104913.1630774065; _gat=1',
    'dnt': '1',
    'origin': 'https://sts.eursc.eu',
    'referer': 'https://sts.eursc.eu/',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Google Chrome";v="93", " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="93"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.63 Safari/537.36'
}

r5 = s.post(login_url5, data=payload2, headers=headers5, cookies=cookies1, allow_redirects=False)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r5.text, 'html.parser')
print(f'RESPONSE 5: {r5.status_code}, {soup.title}')
print(r5.url)
PHPSESSID = r5.headers['set-cookie'].split('PHPSESSID=')[1].split(';')[0]
print(r5.headers)

cookies2 = {
    '_ga': 'GA1.2.158382224.1620157877',
    'LOCAL_LANGUAGE_CODE': 'en',
    'browse_history': '%5B%22%5C%2Fcontent%5C%2Fcommon%5C%2Fdashboard.php%22%5D',
    '_gid': 'GA1.2.1105104913.1630774065',
    '_gat': '1',
    'PHPSESSID': PHPSESSID
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
RESPONSE 1: 200, <title>Schola Europaea - MySchool</title>
RESPONSE 2: 200, <title>Sign In</title>
RESPONSE 3: 200, <title>Working...</title>
https://sts.eursc.eu:443/adfs/ls/?SAMLRequest=lVNNj5swEL3...jug%2BXQ%3D%3D&client-request-id=0000...280077
RESPONSE 4: 307, <title>307 Temporary Redirect</title>
https://sms.eursc.eu/saml/module.php/saml/sp/saml2-acs.php/euroschools
{'Date': 'Sun, 05 Sep 2021 20:18:58 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=iso-8859-1', 'Content-Length': '247', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Server': 'Apache', 'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'Referrer-Policy': 'no-referrer-when-downgrade', 'Location': 'https://sms.eursc.eu/saml/login_check', 'Cache-Control': 'max-age=31536000', 'Expires': 'Mon, 05 Sep 2022 20:18:57 GMT'}
RESPONSE 5: 302, <title>Redirecting to https://sms.eursc.eu/login</title>
https://sms.eursc.eu/saml/login_check
{'Date': 'Sun, 05 Sep 2021 20:18:58 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', 'Content-Length': '350', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Server': 'Apache', 'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'Referrer-Policy': 'no-referrer-when-downgrade', 'Set-Cookie': 'PHPSESSID=8srt20evkmlmnkh0dgpbbm5hkt; path=/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=lax', 'Cache-Control': 'post-check=0, pre-check=0', 'Location': 'https://sms.eursc.eu/login', 'Expires': 'Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT', 'X-Msm-Instance': '(D=22169,t=1630873135774629)', 'X-XSS-Protection': '0; mode=block', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'Content-Security-Policy': "frame-ancestors 'self';", 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload', 'Pragma': 'no-cache'}
```

```
EXPECTED r5 Response Headers:
{...'location': 'https://sms.eursc.eu/', 'contetn-lenght': '330'...}
RECIVED r5 Response Headers:
{...[enter image description here][1]'location': 'https://sms.eursc.eu/login', 'contetn-lenght': '350'...}
```

[1st POST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsrHH.png)

[2nd POST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NM44E.jpg)

These is literally the last step, I would gratelly appreciate any help, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

SOLVED :D

The code was just an absolute chaos, I ended up by redoing it from scratch and went from 200 lines to 50. The main problems were overating request headers and going through 'r1' and 'r2' which both were useless and forced me to use Google Analitycs cookies which I had no idea of how to handle with python requests. I'm not posting the code because although it is quite simple I is just not right to post it here without permission (I'll leave the past verssion but I'm not uploading the new one).

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.